# copy paste range if there's no match excel

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm quite new with vba and would need your precious help.
I want to copy paste a range after the last row if I can't find a match between column B in sheet "all" and column A in sheet "FY23".
My goal is for it to copy paste the range the number of times there's not a match. So if there's 3 values not found in column B it should copy paste 3 times and with my current code it only copy pastes once...

I also want to add the values that are not found in the second cell of the first row copied, not sure how to do that either.
e.g. i can't find "hello" on column B so it will copy paste my range and add "hello" to the 2nd cell of the first row copied.

Thank you a lot in advance.

```
Sub copypaste()
   
    Dim all As Worksheet, fy23 As Worksheet
    Dim allLastRow As Long, fy23LastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim dataRng As Range

    Set all = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ALL")
    Set fy23 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FY23")

    allLastRow = all.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    allLastRow = allLastRow + 3

    fy23LastRow = fy23.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set dataRng = fy23.Range("A2:A" & fy23LastRow)

    For x = 2 To allLastRow

        On Error Resume Next

        If Not all.Range("B" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(all.Range("B" & x).Value, dataRng, 1, False) Then
            Sheets("ALL").Range("A1:BB22").Copy
            Sheets("ALL").Range("A" & allLastRow).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: What are the values of allLastRow and fy23LastRow ? If there is an empty Cell in the column A of the sheet fy23 or an empty cell in the column B of the sheet all the number of row could be misscalculated

Comment: Hi, there's indeed a lot of empty cells on Column B but none on Column A.